# Need to make photos appear in random order but maintain side by side responsiveness.

Tags: php, css, html

So I wrote a code to make 4 photos (or more) be responsive (Pinboard like) but I can't figure out how to make the photos be random.

Example: You visit the page and you see img  A: B: C :D  Then when you refresh the page there is a different set of images. I know there is plenty of tutorials to randomize photos but I haven't found anything with the pinboard like design that I created.

Could really use some help in understanding what code I need to add to make the photos change with each page refresh instead of always showing the same photos.

[image: Showing how front end looks.]

HERES MY CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
margin: 0;
font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
text-align: center;
padding: 32px;
}

.row {
display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
flex-wrap: wrap;
padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
-ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
flex: 25%;
max-width: 25%;
padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
margin-top: 8px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

/* RL - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.column {
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other 
instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.column {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
}
</style>
<body>

<!-- Header -->
<div class="header">
<h1>Responsive Image Grid</h1>
<p>Testing system.</p>
</div>

<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row"> 
<div class="column">
<img src="/public/admin/haleyfoxforabout333.jpg" style="width:100%">

</div>
<div class="column">
<img src="/public/user/2c/04/d72477bc8b54505d2027a5966f941252.jpg" 
style="width:100%">

</div>  
<div class="column">
<img src="/public/album_photo/3b/04/0196544bb5fdd97b9a40e49327394756.jpg" 
style="width:100%">

</div>
<div class="column">
<img src="/public/user/ca/03/8a344be65723d3d001f1b34acb5f6742.jpg" 
style="width:100%">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

NEW CODE after a suggestion from someone. (Still not working give an error.)

```
  <br>
  <br>
  <h50><?php echo $this->translate('Be Discovered!'); ?></h50>
  and connected. Meet anyone & see everything!</a></p>
  <br>        

 <?php

 $pics = [
 "/public/admin/haleyfoxforabout333.jpg",
 "/public/user/2c/04/d72477bc8b54505d2027a5966f941252.jpg",
 "/public/user/ca/03/8a344be65723d3d001f1b34acb5f6742.jpg",           
 "/public/album_photo/3b/04/0196544bb5fdd97b9a40e49327394756.jpg"
 ];

 shuffle($pics);
 ?>

 <style>


 h50 {
 padding: 0 30px 8px;
 width: auto;
 font-size: 40px;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #D2DBE8;
 border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
 display: inline-block;
 }

 .headerz {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 32px;
 }

 .rowz {
 display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
 display: flex;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 padding: 0 4px;
            }

 /* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
 .columnz {
 -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
 flex: 25%;
 max-width: 25%;
 padding: 0 4px;
 }

 .columnz img {
 margin-top: 8px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }

 /* RL - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
 @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 .columnz {
 -ms-flex: 50%;
 flex: 50%;
 max-width: 50%;
 }
 }

 /* RL Takes the two columns stack on top of each other. */
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .columnz {
 -ms-flex: 100%;
 flex: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 }
 }

 </style>

 <!-- Photo Grid -->
 <div class="rowz">

 <?php
 foreach($pics as $pic){
 echo '<div class="column">';
 echo '<img src="'..'" style="width:100%">';
 echo '</div>';
 }
 ?>    

 <?php
 foreach($pics as $pic){
 echo '<div class="column">';
 echo '<img src="'..'" style="width:100%">';
 echo '</div>';
 }
 ?> 

 <?php
 foreach($pics as $pic){
 echo '<div class="column">';
 echo '<img src="'..'" style="width:100%">';
 echo '</div>';
 }
 ?> 

 <?php
 foreach($pics as $pic){
 echo '<div class="column">';
 echo '<img src="'..'" style="width:100%">';
 echo '</div>';
 }
 ?> 

 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The shuffle() function randomizes the order of the elements in the array.
>
> This function assigns new keys for the elements in the array. Existing keys will be removed

```
....
<?php

$pics = [
    "/public/admin/haleyfoxforabout333.jpg",
    "/public/user/2c/04/d72477bc8b54505d2027a5966f941252.jpg",
    "/public/user/ca/03/8a344be65723d3d001f1b34acb5f6742.jpg",
    "/public/album_photo/3b/04/0196544bb5fdd97b9a40e49327394756.jpg"
];

shuffle($pics);
?>
<body>

<!-- Header -->
<div class="header">
<h1>Responsive Image Grid</h1>
<p>Testing system.</p>
</div>

<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row">

    <?php
    foreach($pics as $pic){
        echo '<div class="column">';
        echo '<img src="'..'" style="width:100%">';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?> 
</div>
</body>
.
```

FULL CODE:

HERES MY CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
margin: 0;
font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
text-align: center;
padding: 32px;
}

.row {
display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
flex-wrap: wrap;
padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
-ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
flex: 25%;
max-width: 25%;
padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
margin-top: 8px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

/* RL - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.column {
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
}
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other 
instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.column {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
}
</style>
<body>

<!-- Header -->
<div class="header">
<h1>Responsive Image Grid</h1>
<p>Testing system.</p>
</div>

<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row"> 
<div class="column">
<img src="/public/admin/haleyfoxforabout333.jpg" style="width:100%">

</div>
<div class="column">
<img src="/public/user/2c/04/d72477bc8b54505d2027a5966f941252.jpg" 
style="width:100%">

</div>  
<div class="column">
<img src="/public/album_photo/3b/04/0196544bb5fdd97b9a40e49327394756.jpg" 
style="width:100%">

</div>
<div class="column">
<img src="/public/user/ca/03/8a344be65723d3d001f1b34acb5f6742.jpg" 
style="width:100%">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

NEW CODE after a suggestion from someone. (Still not working give an error.)

```
  <br>
  <br>
  <h50><?php echo $this->translate('Be Discovered!'); ?></h50>
  and connected. Meet anyone & see everything!</a></p>
  <br>        
            
 <?php
            
 $pics = [
 "/public/admin/haleyfoxforabout333.jpg",
 "/public/user/2c/04/d72477bc8b54505d2027a5966f941252.jpg",
 "/public/user/ca/03/8a344be65723d3d001f1b34acb5f6742.jpg",           
 "/public/album_photo/3b/04/0196544bb5fdd97b9a40e49327394756.jpg"
 ];
            
 shuffle($pics);
 ?>
            
 <style>
            
            
 h50 {
 padding: 0 30px 8px;
 width: auto;
 font-size: 40px;
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #D2DBE8;
 border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
 display: inline-block;
 }
            
 .headerz {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 32px;
 }
            
 .rowz {
 display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
 display: flex;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 padding: 0 4px;
            }
            
 /* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
 .columnz {
 -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
 flex: 25%;
 max-width: 25%;
 padding: 0 4px;
 }
            
 .columnz img {
 margin-top: 8px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }
            
 /* RL - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
 @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 .columnz {
 -ms-flex: 50%;
 flex: 50%;
 max-width: 50%;
 }
 }
            
 /* RL Takes the two columns stack on top of each other. */
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .columnz {
 -ms-flex: 100%;
 flex: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 }
 }
            
 </style>
            
 <!-- Photo Grid -->
 <div class="rowz">
 
 <?php
 foreach($pics as $pic){
 echo '<div class="column">';
 echo '<img src="'.$pic.'" style="width:100%">';
 echo '</div>';
 }
 ?>    

 </div>
```

Comment: Iv added the code you give me but it gives me an error code. I attached the edited code above. You see it also at Zoeaa.com

Comment: all pics url in $pics array ... shuffle it ... and then echo.... only one foreach is require!!

Comment: Follow up question if you don't mind!  The code works great but for example, let's say I only want to show four (4) photos at a time, but i want it to sort through twenty (20) possible pictures. That way there is a new photo shown on refresh. How would I do that?

Comment: image stored in DB or array? if all image in $pics array use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php instance of ```shuffle``` =>  ```$rand_index = array_rand($pics, 4);``` then ```foreach($rand_index as $index){echo '<img src = "'.$pics[$index].'" />';}```